# Pass an object as argument with gdbus utility

Tags: linux, bash, bluetooth, bluez, gdbus

I want to call method `RegisterAgent` with `gdbus` but I can't find the proper syntax to do so.

Introspecting on `/org/bluez` with this command

```
$ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.bluez --object-path /org/bluez --recurse
```

shows that method `RegisterAgent` on interface `org.bluez.AgentManager1` has the following signature:

```
RegisterAgent(in  o agent,
              in  s capability);
```

but I can't find any example showing how to pass an *object* to a method in the [gdbus reference documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gio/gdbus.html), nor in the numerous examples I've found on the Internet.

So I don't know how to pass an agent as first argument, for example I'd like to select `KeyboardOnly` as agent, but how can this be done?

With `dbus-send`, this gives:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez \
    --type=method_call org.bluez.AgentManager1.RegisterAgent \
    objpath:/org/bluez/agent1 string:KeyboardOnly
```

But I can't find how to do this with a **gdbus** call. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spied on the actual commands sent through DBus using

```
dbus-monitor  --system
```

With trial and error, I finally found the correct syntax.

The gdbus command I was trying to make can be spelled like so:

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.bluez --method \
    org.bluez.AgentManager1.RegisterAgent --object-path /org/bluez \ 
    /org/bluez/agent KeyboardOnly
```

So *passing an object as parameter to gdbus* is done by spelling its path, for instance `/org/bluez/agent` in our case. It seems to me this is not documented.

By the way, the corresponding `dbus-send` command is spelled *almost* the same

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez \
    --type=method_call org.bluez.AgentManager1.RegisterAgent \
    objpath:/org/bluez/agent1 string:KeyboardOnly
```

but for the agent object path... /org/bluez/**agent1** for `dbus-send`, and just /org/bluez/**agent** for `gdbus`. I don't think this aspect is documented either.